# Dropping a row in a dataframe [has text instead of a number [probably easy] (pandas, dataframe, python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'num legs': [2, 4, 0, Infinity], 'num wings': [2, 0, NHN, 5], 'num arms': [2, 0, NHN, 5]})
....

>>> df
num legs  num wings  num arms
       2          2         6
       4          0         4
       0        NHN         1
Infinity          5         0
```

How would I go about getting it to look through a column for non-text and removing that row. Lets say I'd like to remove the row with NHN and Infinity because it contains text when it should be numerical values only?

I was thinking of doing something like:
`df = df[~df['num legs','num wings', 'num arms'].isin(['NHN, Infinity'])]`

But my dataset has 80 columns, 2 of which should have text in their values, and 78 should be numerical only.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the rows where all the fields are int:

```
pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[i] for i in range(len(df)) if type(df['num wings'][i]) is int and type(df['num legs'][i]) is int and type(df['num arms'][i]) is int])
```

Answer (score 1):

First specify columns which are numeric:

```
cols = ['num legs','num wings', 'num arms']
```

Or specified non numeric columns and for numeric use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
exclude = ['non numeric1','non numeric1']
cols = df.columns.difference(exclude)
```

And then convert non numeric to NaNs by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and last remove rows with them by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

#remove only NaNs rows
df = df.dropna(subset=cols)

#remove NaN, +inf and -inf rows
df = df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Would using the dropna drop values that aren't just "NA" (non traditional NA) such as "infinity"?

Comment: @DenisVecchiato - No, it convert to `inf`. If need remove this values use `df = df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a function:-

```
import numpy as np

def func(val):
    if type(val)==str:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return val
```

Now just use this:-

```
df=df.applymap(func).dropna().astype(int)
```